# How to create setup.py with library file as stand alone

Tags: python, package, libraries, setup.py

I have a problem, i develop an application with python and i use some libraries like flask, sqlalchemy, etc...

The problem is that i have a define version of each library, and I want to deploy this python application in another computer without internet,
can I create a package or use setup.py and include the other package with path ?

I've already try this code, but the library aren't imported they said that :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

My code is:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
# Application name:
name="MyApplication",

# Version number (initial):
version="0.1.0",

# Packages
packages=["App","App/service"],
include_package_data=True,
install_requires=[
    "flask","cx_Oracle","pandas","sqlalchemy"
],
)
```

Comment: I edited your answer, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

install_requires is a setuptools setup.py keyword that should be used to *specify* what a project minimally needs to run correctly.

It won’t install those libraries.

Maybe you should try pyinstaller (https://www.pyinstaller.org) to make ready runnable file to run on the other computer.

Comment: The problem is that the "standalone" generated have to work en linux and windows platform I don't think pyinstaller can do that

Comment: You can make 2 "standalone": one for Windows and one for Linux.